# Расширение для chrome, onBeforeSendHeaders работа с вебсокетами

Tags: javascript, websocket, chrome-extension, httpwebrequest

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь перехватить запрос на открытие вебсокета с помощью `webRequest`, ничего не выходит, при этом обычные `XMLHttpRequest` запросы спокойно перехватываются, можно было бы предположить, что коннект к вебсокету нельзя перехватить, но в документации четко написано:

> Starting from Chrome 58, the webRequest API supports intercepting the WebSocket handshake request. Since the handshake is done by means of an HTTP upgrade request, its flow fits into HTTP-oriented webRequest model

пример кода перехвата запросов:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    console.log(details);
},
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Здесь в консоль выдаются все запросы, кроме запроса на коннект с вебсокетом, подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как все-таки этот вебсокет перехватить.

Answer (score 0):

1. Убедитесь что в манифесте запрошены разрешения для протоколов `ws://` и `wss://`;
2. Попробуйте отловить handshake по событию `onBeforeRequest`.